# Foreign key with multiple table options

Tags: mysql, foreign-key, architecture, hierarchy

I'm not sure if the title is very good, feel free to suggest a better one.

People can "comment" on different objects of my site,similarly to StackExchange (for example they can comment on a Question, an Answer or a Comment).
The way I've decided to design it is something like this:

```
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `comment` (
  `id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `user_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL COMMENT 'Who voted' ,
  `object_type` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL COMMENT 'The table or class name of the voted object. Such as \"answer\", \"question\", ...' ,
  `object_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL COMMENT 'The primary key of the object being voted on' ,
  `value` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL COMMENT '+1, -1 or 0 for a comment' ,
  `content` TEXT NULL COMMENT 'A free text comment about the object' ,
  `votes` INT UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT 0 COMMENT 'How many votes did this comment receive' ,
  `create_time` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`) ,
  INDEX `fk_vote_user` (`user_id` ASC) ,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_vote_user`
    FOREIGN KEY (`user_id` )
    REFERENCES `user` (`id` )
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB
COMMENT = 'Keeps track of \"upvotes\" or \"downvotes\" of content.'
```

Probably too much info for here but basically I'm taking the approach of a generic "object_type" VARCHAR ("QUESTION" for example) and an "object_id".

Is this a good approach? Can I make foreign keys? What would you suggest to improve performance?

I am using MySQL and PHP (and Yii).

Comment: Definitely you can make FKs.  Performancewise, hard to say anything without knowing about the load of your site.  Could you amend your question with this?

Comment: The site does not exist yet, no load. You are saying you can make foreign keys even though the field "object_type" will dynamically define which table it refers to?

Comment: But you probably have plans about how big the load will be :)  About foreign keys: how many different types do you have?  If not many (say 4-5) and you will have a few hundred thousand rows at least, I would consider adding a separate field (and FK) for each.  Otherwise, `object_type` can be a FK (with its ID) as well.

Comment: No, I don't think this is the correct approach. See this question: [Implementing comments and Likes in database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8112831/implementing-comments-and-likes-in-database/8113064#8113064) You need a supertype table (called `Entity` in that answer) that the FK in your `comment` table can reference.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of object_id and object_type columns, why not use a primary key for each object type to be commented on, but maintain the object_type (for partitioning later) so that you have question_id, comment_id, and answer_id. For each row of data, two of the columns will be null, but it is easy on your ORM (single table inheritance with a type qualifier).

Your queries will also join to the correct FK, I am not sure of the space usage for this, but I expect it to be very performant since the joins do not need additional filters on the where clause for different types as well as complex "SQL join acrobatics"

Comment: Sounds good. Although I'm not sure I understood "but maintain the object_type (for partitioning later)".

Comment: object_type would contain a value for what type of object is being commented on. I would recommend tinyint unsigned (1-256) with values like 1 for Question, 2 for Answer, 3 for Comment etc. 

If the table grows too large you can create the partitions on this column to speed up queries. I would also recommend an index on this column

Comment: It is possible to have a restriction in the database (mysql in my case) so only one of the fields be not null?

Comment: You can try to use triggers which can lead to a host of problems, however I would recommend putting that kind of logic into the application code or middle layer since its not native database functionality